# Statistical Approaches for Uncertain Target Variable

Tags: regression, classification, bayesian, dataset, hidden-markov-model

Let me first explain what I have tried to mean by *uncertain target variable*. Consider the following scenario:

**Illegal immigrant behavior:** Suppose you want to interdict with illegal immigrants to catch them enter a country. Let say they wait/observe some certain condition set $X$ (e.g., patrol schedule(if known somehow), hour of the day, day of the week, weather conditions, etc.) to move and pass the border. $X$ can be observed both by you and the immigrants. Let $Y$ be the immigrants' action: $1$, if they try; $0$, otherwise. Apparently, $Y$ is known by the immigrants, but you may not always be interdicting with them, so that you are uncertain about their action. Meaning that when you do not interdict/detect illegal border pass, you assume the corresponding $Y$ is $0$. However, there might (no may not) had been illegal passes that you do not know. In that case, you are **uncertain** about the target variable $Y$.

Now, I have a dataset consist of $Y$ and $X$. I believe that any conclusion derived by performing regression or classification analysis might be misguided by undetected activities. The question is the following:

- What statistical tools are available for this type of dataset?

After doing some research, I feel that Hidden Markov Models could be one of them to deal with the uncertainty, but of course, I am not sure.

Regards.